# My number value isn't updating, how do I fix it?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I was trying to make it so that every second the loop changed the value of the number value but it keeps returning either `nil` or `0`. I tried adding it as a local value that affected the actual value and a few other things like making it a string instead and replacing the string with a new one but that still didn't return anything. This is my code now and it's the code that returns `0` and not `nil` or an error.

```
local SecondsAfterGameStart = game.ServerStorage.SecondsAfterGameStart.Value

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    SecondsAfterGameStart = SecondsAfterGameStart + 1
end
```

Comment: Did you try to use WaitForChild on its parent, then itself? Also, the way to get ServerStorage is to use GetService to get the instance. Check this post https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ServerStorage

Comment: Yea the waitforchild didn't work

Answer (score 2):

When you save `SecondsAfterGameStart.Value` into a local variable, you are not keeping a reference to the original NumberValue object, you are copying its value into the local variable. Later in your while loop, you are accessing and modifying a variable and not the original object, so changes are never saved back to the object in the ServerStorage.

So, instead of saving the Value, hold onto the entire NumberValue itself. Then you can update the Value directly.

```
local SecondsAfterGameStart = game.ServerStorage.SecondsAfterGameStart

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    SecondsAfterGameStart.Value += 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try it!