# Attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

Tags: lua, roblox

So basicially i wanted to make a tower defense game, I added a button which on click spawn in towers / robots with AI. (the script is local) It always errors me with **Attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'**. (I know that this means the game doesnt know what leaderstats is), I made a script that makes the folder called leaderstats inside of the player with the coins and stuff inside but it still doesnt know that theres a leaderstats folder. I also tried out FindFirstChild() but it just said **Attempt to index nil with 'FindFirstChild'**. Can anyone help me?

```
local button = script.Parent

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function(player)
        local spawner = game.Workspace.ts1
    local money = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value
        if money >= 250 then
            money = money - 250
            local clone = game.ReplicatedStorage.Allies.Guard:Clone()
            clone.Parent = workspace
            clone.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = spawner.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
        else
            if money <= 250 then
            button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
            button.Text = "Too Expensive"
            wait(0.5)
            button.Text = "Guard [250$]"
                button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0.603922, 0.603922, 0.603922)

            end
        end
    end)
```

Comment: `Attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'. (I know that this means the game doesnt know what leaderstats is)` - No. It means `player` is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MouseButton1 event on GuiButtons](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/GuiButton/MouseButton1Click) doesn't provide any arguments, so your `player` variable ends up being nil. And when you try to say `player.leaderstats`, it throws the error because player doesn't have any children or properties to index because it is nil.

But since this is a LocalScript, you can easily access the Player object using the [Players.LocalPlayer](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer) object.

```
local button = script.Parent
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect( function()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
```

Comment: The attempt index nil is fixed, but i have another problem: whenever the "Guard" spawns, his AI scripts dont work... any fix? It also doesnt take any money from you

Comment: Regarding the money, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058951/my-number-value-isnt-updating-how-do-i-fix-it). I have no idea why the AI scripts aren't working, you'll need to figure that one out on your own.

Comment: Finally, After 3 months i have decided to work on it again. I now got the money and tower AI fixed: the tower AI broke because a local script spawned it in a GUI. I used remote events and now it works. There is only one error remaining: In the game you get 10 cash every 5 seconds. When you buy the tower you lose 250 cash, but after you get 10 cash after the 5 second mark you get the lost cash back from buying the tower..?

Comment: nevermind i might have realized why: cause its a local script, lemme use the normal script instead

Comment: i used the normal script and it worked, now i can finally start making a major update on my tower defense game, thanks so much