# My script is not able to change the value for some reason(roblox)

Tags: roblox

So I made a button, which when get pressed, give a player who pressed it an armor. To check if player already has an armor i create a bool value using Instance.new and check the value inside the button script. But for some reason, the value doesnt change at all even tho i typed the correct path.

Here is the button script:

```
function giveArmor(Clicker)
    local newArmor = game.ServerStorage["Light vest VOG-1"]:Clone()
    local charatcer = Clicker.Character
    local humanoid = charatcer.Humanoid
    local isArmorOn = humanoid.ArmorFolder:WaitForChild("IsArmorOn").Value
    print(isArmorOn)
    if isArmorOn == false then
        newArmor.Parent = charatcer
        newArmor.Name = "InGameArmor"
        isArmorOn = true
        humanoid.ArmorFolder:WaitForChild("PhysicalDamageResist").Value = 0.85
        humanoid.ArmorFolder:WaitForChild("ArmorName").Value = "Light vest VOG-1"
    end
end

script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(giveArmor)
```

And here is the script that creates new values:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
        local humanoid = Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        --//Stuff in armor folder//------------------------------
        local armorFolder = Instance.new("Folder", humanoid)
        armorFolder.Name = "ArmorFolder"
        local pResist = Instance.new("NumberValue", armorFolder)
        pResist.Name = "PhysicalDamageResist"
        pResist.Value = 1
        local mResist = Instance.new("NumberValue", armorFolder)
        mResist.Name = "MentalDamageResist"
        mResist.Value = 1
        local cResist = Instance.new("NumberValue", armorFolder)
        cResist.Name = "CompoundDamageResist"
        cResist.Value = 1.5
        local tResist = Instance.new("NumberValue", armorFolder)
        tResist.Name = "TruePhysicalDamageResist"
        tResist.Value = 2
        local armorName = Instance.new("StringValue", armorFolder)
        armorName.Name = "ArmorName"
        armorName.Value = "None"
        local armorCheck = Instance.new("BoolValue", armorFolder)
        armorCheck.Name = "IsArmorOn"
        armorCheck.Value = false
        --//SP//-----------------------------------------------
        local maxSP = Instance.new("NumberValue", humanoid)
        maxSP.Name = "MaxSP"
        maxSP.Value = 100
        local sp = Instance.new("NumberValue", humanoid)
        sp.Name = "SP"
        sp.Value = 100
        --//Other stuff//-------------------------------------
        humanoid.NameDisplayDistance = 0 -- Disable name display
        Character.Health.Disabled = true -- Disable regen
    end)
end)
```

Comment: You are running into the same problem as this guy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058951/my-number-value-isnt-updating-how-do-i-fix-it/68060099#68060099. See if the answer helps you with your problem

Comment: Thanks again Kylaa, you are a life saviour

Answer (score 0):

when you define the isArmorOn variable you immediately set it to what state the bool is in. this means that the variable only contains either True or False but not wherefrom it got that value. instead what you should do is:

```
local isArmorOn = humanoid.ArmorFolder:WaitForChild("IsArmorOn").Value
--and for changing the variable
isArmorOn.Value = true
```